# Regex that not ending with smaller case

Tags: python, regex

creating the regex which is having at least 3 chars and not end with

```
import re
re.findall(r'(\w{3,})(?![a-z])\b','I am tyinG a mixed charAv case VOW')
```

My Out

```
['tyinG', 'mixed', 'charAv', 'case', 'VOW']
```

My Expected is

```
['tyinG', 'VOW']
```

I am getting the proper out when i am doing the `re.findall(r'(\w{3,})(?<![a-z])\b','I am tyinG a mixed charAv case VOW')`

when i did the je.im my first regex which doesnot having `<` giving correct only

[image]

What is the relevance of `<` here

Comment: That's a negative lookbehind. Without `<`, it's negative lookahead.

Comment: So with negative lookbehind, you are asking for strings that do not have `[a-z]` before `\b`.

Comment: try this regexp: `(\w{2,}([A-Z]\b))`.  basically, I am trying to assert capital letters at the end(you modify this accordingly) instead of using the negation of lower case letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern `(\w{3,})(?![a-z])\b` does not give you the expected result because the pattern is first matching 3+ word chars and then asserts using a negative lookahead `(?!` that what is directly on the right is not a lowercase char a-z.

That assertion will be true as the lowercase a-z chars are already matched by `\w`

---

The second pattern `(\w{3,})(?<![a-z])\b` does give you the right result as it first tries to match 3 or more word chars and after that asserts using a negative lookbehind `(?<!` what is directly to the left is not a lowercase char a-z.

---

If you want to use a lookaround, you can make the pattern a bit more efficient by making use of a word boundary at the beginning.

At the end of the pattern place the negative lookbehind after the word boundary to first anchor it and then do the assertion.

```
\b\w{3,}\b(?<![a-z])
```

**Note** that you can omit the capturing group if you want the single match only.